# Downloading string from views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is is possible to use the data_send method from a view in my rails project?

so far i've been trying this in my view

```
//<%= send_data( "myString", :filename => "download.txt" ) %>
```

I get a error saying

```
undefined method `send_data'
```

Do i need to require something?

Comment: I don't think so. What are you trying to do here? You cannot send any other content when doing `send_data` so why can't you put it into a controller?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't make *any* sense. If you're in a view, by definition you've opted to render your view and your request is already sending data (buffering not withstanding). You can't both send HTML (or XML or JSON or whichever type of view you're rendering) to the browser, *and* send a file called "download.txt" to the browser, in one request.

You need a second action, which your view links to, and which outputs the file with `send_data` in the controller.